# EF6 Call stored procedure with parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, edmx

I have a stored procedure in MySQL that accepts an integer and returns multiple resultsets.
From what I understand, I see this is one way to do it.

```
var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "CALL `GetBlogPosts`(@BlogId)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = "BlogId", Value = 1 });
```

But am get this error:

```
The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.
```

If I change the command to this

```
cmd.CommandText = "CALL `GetBlogPosts`({@BlogId})";
```

I am getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1})' at line 1
```

Comment: What is `GetBlogPosts` and it's definition? Why do you need `{` and `}` in your second example?

Comment: Well `GetBlogPosts` accepts just one input param of type int and returns multiple result sets. Is the definition important? I've read somewhere the usage of `{}` and tried that too, but did not work.